# Save continuous telegram in to different folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, telnet

I have a problem with saving output from the telegram. My problem is, from server I am getting data every minutes. My VERY SIMPLE CODE can save this continuous data into a .txt file.

But what I want is, to store this data in a daily folder. From this code, while running, it creates current day folder but keep adding next day data in the same folder and also in the same file.

My sample code is:

```
#!/bin/bash


foldername=$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir -p  /home/bash-test/"$foldername"

echolog(){
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then cat - | while read -r message
        do
                echo "$(date -u +"%F %T %Z ; ") $message" | tee -a $MY_LOG
            done
    else
        echo -n "$(date -u +'%F %T %Z') ; " | tee -a $MY_LOG
        echo $* | tee -a $MY_LOG
    fi
}

telnet 197.204.12.253 1001 | echolog > /home/bash-test/"$foldername"/Ppt_$(date +%Y%m%d).txt
```

Comment: Get it restarted somehow to renew `$foldername` and `Ppt_$(date +%Y%m%d).txt`

Comment: @Ivan yes If I restarted at midnight then it will create another folder and save it to new but then I have to close the connection and need to connect it. I was thinking if there is any way to do without closing connection.

Comment: Or leave permanent file name and use `logrotate` to make day files, not sure if it's able to rotate folders as well.

Comment: @bikuser : Test in your loop if the date has changed, and if it does, reassign `foldername` to the new name. Aside from this, you seem to have forgotten to set your variable `MY_LOG`.

Comment: @user1934428, In loop it creates folder but still keep adding data in to older files. Yes I tested with MY_LOG. while defining it, produce a new file outside folder. Or maybe I misunderstood, COZ I am in very basic level :( .

Comment: First, I don't see any folder creation inside the loop. The only `mkdir` is at the start of the script. Second, you set up your `echolog` redirection exactly once, and never change it. Inside your loop, you need to recognize that the date has changed, and if it does, you have to return from your `echolog` function, to allow the caller to set up a new redirection. Consider putting the folder creation into inside the loop, and pass the base directory (`/home/bash-test`) as  parameter to `echolog`.  The invocation would then just be `telnet blabla | echolog /home/bash-test`.

Comment: @user1934428, I had it before, but it didn't help, maybe I did some wrong. But I will try it again with making 120 sleep.

Comment: I don't see in your posting what you had before. I can only discuss what you are posting. Aside from this, I don't see how a _sleep_ would help anything with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh now I've got it, 'echolog' is your function, I though it's some app at first sought. It could be simplified like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

fun(){
    while read data; do
        printf -v folder '%(%Y%m%d)T' -1
        printf -v filenm 'test_%(Y%m%d_%h%s)T.txt' -1
        mkdir -p $folder &> /dev/null
        echo "$data" >> "$folder/$filenm"
    done
}

tail -f file | fun
```